# Git with TFS and exclusive checkouts

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, git, version-control, tfs

I would like some advice on how to use Git locally on my computer along with Visual Studio and a TFS server. Unfortunately the technical leader of my company has set TFS with the **exclusive check-out** policy and so every time someone checks out a file, it can't be edited by someone else.

What is the right way to make the two systems live together? I would try to use *Git-TF* but I'm not convinced with the checkin phase. The workflow should be as the following:

1. clone the project
2. switch to offline mode for Visual Studio
3. work offline with Git
4. fetch from the TFS server and rebase
5. *check-in?*

The problem is: how do I check-in my files if someone else has already checked out the files I need to change? How does Git-TF really work when checking-in files?

Another workflow that came to my mind, without Git-TF, could be the following:

1. open the TFS project
2. switch to offline mode
3. create a new branch with Git
4. work on the branch
5. return to the master branch, update it
6. exclusively checkout the files which have been changed on my Git branch
7. merge the branch on master
8. *check in with TFS (after switch to online mode?)*

What do you recommend?

Comment: What do you mean you're "not convinced"?  What do you mean "how does it really work"?

Comment: I am not convinced because of the note "how do I check-in my files if someone else has already checked out the files I need to change?". About your second question: when you check-in with Git-TF, does it behave as you would manually do by checking-out the files, applying changes and checking-in again (but in a single shot)?

Comment: Convince your team lead to turn off Exclusive Checkouts. You're getting into a whole lot of a mess.

Comment: If it were me, I would pick the second workflow. After working with TFS and VSS, I've become leery of non-exclusive checkouts with those products, but YMMV.

Comment: @StockBreak: `git-tf` can't checkin if there's a lock, just like any other TFS client.  `git-tf` simply looks at the differences to a file between the last changeset and the `HEAD` of your git repository and tries to apply those changes and check-in.  Nothing magic.

Comment: @EdwardThomson: ok, thanks!  
Unfortunately removing exclusive check-outs is not a viable solution at the moment because in my company they are all accustomed to work like this.
I think that I will try my second workflow for now and I will post here the results. Thanks to all anyway.